# What is the easiest way to draw a sphere using Makie.jl in Julia?

Tags: julia, makie.jl

I am trying to get started with Makie.jl and want to test out how to plot a simple sphere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple. Note that you need to have Makie installed which can be done via `] add Makie` in the Julia REPL.

```
using Makie

scene = mesh(Sphere(Point3f0(0), 1f0))
display(scene)
```

[image]

It's also worth noting that Makie windows are interactive! You can zoom in and out as well as rotate around the sphere.